# Golang JSON Unmarshaling of python string

Tags: python, unicode, go, boto

I'm working with an AWS SQS queue where python is putting strings into the queue using boto.  Most of the strings are unicode, but some are in pythons basic string type.

I'm trying to read these messages with GO and running into JSON decode errors:

```
JSON Decode Error: 2 invalid character 'e' looking for beginning of value
```

All these decode errors happen when GO encounters a messages that is not a unicode string but pythons basic string format.

Is there a way of converting python strings into unicode strings from GO? ascii -> unicode?

EDIT:

Here's an example of a working and non working json string. The only way I'm able to get the non working one is through python, GO gives the decode error above

```
Working:
 u'{"queue_time": "1374523279747", "object_id": "5efc90c0912fef247f028f1758082a299c018e8a2c6499289f3426217b14f0ae", "source_bucket": "ap1-cache"}',

Doesn't work:
 '{"queue_time": "1374523279.75026", "source_bucket": "eu1-cache", "object_id": "42e8b7b01ed5919a23d6d91fdc0b540944a5f45e4c387fa1c2bc20e1bf81bdeb"}',
```

Comment: Can you give an example of a working JSON object and a failing one?

Comment: This is a somewhat puzzling question, since the JSON representation has nothing to do with Python's internal data types (it's a serialization format, after all).  Or are you trying to parse `repr` output as JSON, perhaps?

Comment: @BrianDorsey I've added a working and non working JSON strings.

Comment: @Fredrik I'm not too sure my knowledge of encoding is a bit limited. I'm assuming python is passing it's ASCII string to the JSON encoder (encoding the ASCII characters)  and when GO is trying to decode it, GO is assuming it's in Unicode and decoding what it believes to be Unicode?  I'm not sure if that makes sense, but the only thing that I see really different between the two strings is one has `u` prefixing the working string and nothing prefixing the non working string.

Comment: The `u` prefix isn't valid JSON.  But your example output look like Python strings that contain JSON data, not plain JSON as expected by the Go library.  Do you control the code producing these things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To produce proper JSON from Python, you can use the `json` library:

```
>>> d = {"queue_time": "1374523279747", "object_id": "...", "source_bucket": "ap1-cache"}
>>> d
{'queue_time': '1374523279747', 'source_bucket': 'ap1-cache', 'object_id': '...'}

>>> import json
>>> print json.dumps(d)
{"queue_time": "1374523279747", "source_bucket": "ap1-cache", "object_id": "..."}
```

Note that the JSON output looks almost entirely similar for this simple example, but that's not necessarily true for more complicated things.  E.g. tuples and unicode strings have different representations:

```
>>> t = [u"Hello", ("World", "!"), u"\xa0"]
>>> t
[u'Hello', ('World', '!'), u'\xa0']
>>> print json.dumps(t)
["Hello", ["World", "!"], "\u00a0"]
```

Comment: the python code is using the `json` library and producing valid `json` strings because I can get them back in python.  I just can't get the non unicode string to work in GO.

Comment: Yeah, I added this to have something to anchor an answer on.  But the `u` prefix in your example doesn't look right.  If you send that to Go, it'll choke.  But it might be that the problem isn't with serialization, but with how you output the string from Python and send it over to Go.  Can you provide some more details?

Comment: So I just noticed that the one with the `u` prefix is the one that worked for you, not the other way around.  But if you remove the `u` and the extra quotes, you end up with pretty much identical JSON payloads.  From where did you get the examples?  (i.e. who turned one of the JSON payloads into Unicode?)  And if you just read in the raw characters in the Go program and print them out without running them through the JSON decoder, what do you get?

Comment: Found the problem.  Thanks for the "raw characters" bit :) really helped me find out what was going on.  `Boto` encodes it's messages in base64 to the queue and if you're not using boto to read, your message will be left in base64.  Using python to read the messages automatically converts back the ASCII, but in GO it's left as base64 and that's what was being passed in to GO's JSON decoder.  Thanks for you help.

Comment: You can control this in boto.  By using a RawMessage rather than a Message, you can get boto to write the message to the queue without doing the Base64 encoding.